# Find number of simultaneous activites from a list of times

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of activities that contains place, start time and end time. I want to find the number of simultaneous activities at each place. I have found ways to calculate how many other activities a given activity overlaps with using sumproduct, but that gives an incorrect number since the activities may not overlap simultaneously.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please paste in a screenshot of you data, or an example set if you have. Also show your SUMPRODUCT formula in the same, so we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you can categorise or count activities per hour using the following array formula

```
=MMULT(RANDARRAY(1,COUNT(startrange),1,1,TRUE),BITAND({8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}<=endrange,{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}>=startrange))
```

which will output a 1x10 array (for hours 8h00 to 17h00) and count how many events occur in each hour. *startrange* and *endrange* are the column references for the start and end times in hours only (use `=HOUR(B2)` where B2 is an Excel time serial number).

Counting by the hour makes more sense, as otherwise you have to compare each scheduled activity with each other. If three activities overlap each other, that would count as 6 of simultaneous activities. To extend it to count only for a selected place, say "place1":

```
=MMULT(RANDARRAY(1,COUNT(startrange),1,1,TRUE),BITAND({8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}<=endrange*(places="place1"),{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}>=startrange))
```

with *places* the column reference for all the places (equal in length as *endrange* and *startrange*).

Ps. In versions prior to Excel 365, you must enter the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to indicate to Excel it is an array formula.